# Hibernate QueryParameterException Spring MVC & JSON

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jqgrid, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring mvc 3.1 application based on [this tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-mvc-31-jqgrid-and-spring-data_1887.html). I've modified the application to an annotation based application and adapted the view handler to use InternalResourceViewResolver over jstl which is working fine.

In a nutshell the app uses spring mvc, spring data jpa and jqgrid to produce a simple user list which has basic crud mappings passing actions to the controllers through the response ...

When I attempt to modify a record by an update action I'm getting 500 errors (aop trace interceptor ) ...

**Exception** ...

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path    
    [/spring-jqgrid-tutorial] threw exception [Request processing failed;    
    nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
    org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: 
    Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters.    
    Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! 
    ...
    at org.beckett.service.UserService.update(UserService.java:32)
```

**UserService** ...

```
    ...   
public Boolean update( User user ) {
    User existingUser = repository.findByUsername( user.getUsername() );
    if( existingUser == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Only firstName, lastName, and role fields are updatable
    existingUser.setFirstName( user.getFirstName() );
    existingUser.setLastName( user.getLastName() );
    existingUser.getRole().setRole( user.getRole().getRole() );

    User saved = repository.save( existingUser );
    if( saved == null )
        return false; {

    }
    return true;
}

    ...
```

**User Entity**

```
    @Entity( name = "user" ) 
    @NamedQuery( name = User.FIND_BY_USERNAME, 
    query = "select u from user u where u.username = :username" )
    public class User {

    public static final String FIND_BY_USERNAME = "User.findByUsername";

    @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column( unique = true )
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @OneToOne( cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user" )
    private Role role;
...
```

**UserRepository**

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername( String username );

    Page<User> findByUsernameLike( String username, Pageable pageable );

    Page<User> findByFirstNameLike( String firstName, Pageable pageable );

    Page<User> findByLastNameLike( String lastName, Pageable pageable );

    Page<User> findByFirstNameLikeAndLastNameLike( String firstName, String lastName, Pageable pageable );

    @Query( "select u from user u where u.role.role = :role" )
    Page<User> findByRole( @Param( "role" ) Integer role, Pageable pageable );
}
```

**UserController**

```
    @RequestMapping( value = "/update", 
    produces = "application/json", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST )

    public @ResponseBody StatusResponse update( 
           @RequestParam String username, 
           @RequestParam String firstName, 
           @RequestParam String lastName, 
           @RequestParam Integer role ) {

       User existingUser = new User( username, firstName, lastName, new Role( role ) );
       Boolean result = service.update( existingUser );
       return new StatusResponse( result );
}
```

I've seen several threads regarding this exception stating the requirement to change the HQL Query ... However, I'm not sure how to go about debugging this issue ...

Comment: Is there a reason for your named query? The repository should create the query for you.

Comment: I have a jparepo implementation too ... I'll add it to the sample ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by replacing the named parameter with a [positional parameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-parameters) for the Named Query ..

```
    @NamedQuery( name = User.FIND_BY_USERNAME, 
    query = "select u from user u where u.username = ?1" )
```